# Mantis issue_relationship_add

Tags: powershell, mantis

I've got Functions for managing Mantis 'tickets', updating, adding notes, adding attachments but I'm hitting a problem with adding in a relationship to other tickets.
I can read the ticket and get relationships: $mantis = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://tickets.empyreanbenefits.com/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl
$ticketdetails = $mantis.mc_issue_get($Username,$Password,$ticket)
$ticketdetails.relationships

But when I try and add a relationship:

```
$mantis = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://tickets.empyreanbenefits.com/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl
$Relationship = New-Object "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1pi_soap_mantisconnect_php_wsdl.issuerelationshipadd"
$Relationship.id = $Ticket 
$Relationship.Target_id = $TargetID
$Relationship.relationship.id = 3
$mantis.mc_issue_relationship_add($Username, $Password, $ticket, $Relationship)
```

I get this error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1pi_soap_mantisconnect_php_wsdl.issuerelationshipadd]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the method definition:

```
$mantis.mc_issue_relationship_add

# OUTPUT:   
#
# OverloadDefinitions
# -------------------
# string mc_issue_relationship_add(string username, string password, string issue_id, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1pi_soap_mantisconnect_php_wsdl.RelationshipData relationship)
```

You can see that the correct type is `RelationshipData`

```
$Relationship = New-Object ($mantis.GetType().Namespace + ".RelationshipData")
```

Answer (score 1):

Big Thanks to Marsze for response above.

Final script is:

```
$uri = "http://tickets.empyreanbenefits.com/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl"
$mantis = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri
$namespace = $mantis.GetType().Namespace
$relationship = New-Object "$namespace.RelationshipData"
$relationship.id = $Ticket 
$relationship.target_id = $targetId
$type = New-Object "$namespace.ObjectRef"
$type.id = 2
$relationship.type = $type
$mantis.mc_issue_relationship_add($username, $password, $ticket, $relationship)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$mantis = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri http://tickets.empyreanbenefits.com/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl
$ProxyType = $mantis.GetType().Namespace
$Relationship = New-Object("$ProxyType.issuerelationshipadd")
$Relationship.issue_id = $Ticket 
$Relationship.Target_id = $TargetID
$Relationship.relationship.id = 3
$mantis.mc_issue_relationship_add($Username,$Password,$ticket,$Relationship)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response and I gave it a try but no, got pretty mcuh seam error.